# sqlite on mono: calling SELECT causes ResetIndexes and index rebuilding

Tags: c#, linux, sqlite, mono

I'm developing a .net app that is using sqlite to maintain a database. On windows I use System.Data.Sqlite library and everything works fine. On Linux I use Mono.Data.Sqlite. When I start my app and call "SELECT * FROM TagInfo" a strange thing happen. The sqlite starts rebuilding the index without any apparent reason. After finishing rebuilding the app runs normally. As you can imagine, the problem is that index rebuilding is very slow and can take up to 20 minutes. Also, when I restart the app, rebuilding is called again. I'm attaching below the stack trace during the rebuilding.

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing this and how could I prevent it.

Thanks a lot for any info.
gregor

Stack trace:

```
System.Data.Common.Index.MergeSort (to={int[4096]}, length=2821) in /root/mono/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/Index.cs:518
System.Data.Common.Index.Sort () in /root/mono/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/Index.cs:186
System.Data.Common.Index.RebuildIndex () in /root/mono/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/Index.cs:179
System.Data.Common.Index.Reset () in /root/mono/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/Index.cs:160
System.Data.DataTable.ResetIndexes () in /root/mono/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data/DataTable.cs:1485
System.Data.DataTable.set_EnforceConstraints (value=true) in /root/mono/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data/DataTable.cs:623
System.Data.DataTable.EndLoadData () in /root/mono/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data/DataTable.cs:968
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillFromReader (table={}, reader={Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader}, start=0, length=0, mapping={int[4]}, loadOption=System.Data.LoadOption.PreserveChanges) in /root/mono/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/DbDataAdapter.cs:368
System.Data.DataTable.Load (reader={Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader}, loadOption=System.Data.LoadOption.PreserveChanges) in /root/mono/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data/DataTable.cs:2857
System.Data.DataTable.Load (reader={Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader}) in /root/mono/mono-2.10.8/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data/DataTable.cs:2838
GenFiles.SQLiteDatabase.GetDataTable (sql="SELECT * FROM TagInfo") in
```

Comment: the index is not rebuild on the database-level, but in memory for the DataTable. Did you try to give all column names explicit instead of "*" ? Did you try some other load options ?